# ModelState validation gets triggered only for few actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have two actions:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(GetStuffResponse))]
public IHttpActionResult GetStuff([FromUri] RequestObj1 request){}

[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(ValidateStuffResponse))]
public IHttpActionResult ValidateStuff(RequestObj2 request){}
```

My request objects are:

```
public class RequestObj1{
 public int UserId {get;set;}
 //Other properties
}

 public class RequestObj2{
 public int UserId {get;set;}
 //Other properties
}
```

I  have applied Validation filter on both actions:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    #region Public Methods

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

`[ValidateModel]` attribute is applied at the controller level that contains those action.

Now, when I run, `GetStuffs` throws the below `ModelState` exception while `ValidateStuffs` does not.

`"UserId": "The valid is required"`

Not sure what is happening here. Both actions passes thru the validation filter however one method has no `ValidationState` error while other does. Both passes `UserId` as empty. Not sure why is it trigger for one but not for other? 
Any Idea?

Comment: Did you check what is the value it is set during post request? if the value is set to '0' then it is a valid model.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the right direction @KishoreKolla. I checked and found that on the first method the `query string` for `UserId` of GetStuff method is sent as blank. E.g. http://localhost/GetStuffs?Id=1&UserId=      (Blank userId). If you post this as an answer, I'll more as an answer.